# jquery this versus $(this) and maybe even $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often see examples of using the keyword `this` in jquery.  Sometimes I see it used with the $ and parenthesis, other times without. And I thought I saw it used with a little of each.

So,

```
 var id = this.attr('id');

 var id = $(this).attr('id');

 var id = $this.attr('id');
```

Are these all the same? Is there a preferred way?  Is `this` a javascript thing and `$(this)` a jQuery thing? If so, where does `$this` fall?

I know this is probably a total newbie question, but I haven't been able to get the simple, `this`, by itself, to work. I can only get `$(this)` to work.  I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if I've been reading examples with typos.

Comment: 'this' is a js self reference and putting $() just wraps it with jquery class. What refers to $this - it's just a variable name (not predefined) and is usually used in jquery plugins just to always have a reference to the 1st level parent class from child classes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` is a JavaScript thing. It refers to the "context" a function is running in. For most event handlers, it is the ("raw") DOM element that is listening to an event. In other situations it will mean other things; Googling "`this` in JavaScript" might be enlightening.

---

I say it is the "raw" DOM element because jQuery is often used to *wrap* plain DOM elements in a jQuery wrapper, so you can use jQuery methods like `attr` instead of the usual ones (`getAttribute`, `setAttribute`, etc.). This wrapping is accomplished with the `$` function, and that's where you see `$(this)`. For example:

```
this.getAttribute("href")
/* or */ someElement.getAttribute("href")
```

is the same as

```
$(this).attr("href")
/* or */ $(someElement).attr("href")
```

---

`$this` or `this$` is just a variable name. But, it is often conventional to do an assignment like

```
var $this = $(this);
```

The reason for this is to avoid continually invoking the `$` function, which is somewhat expensive as it creates a new jQuery wrapper object every time. If you store the wrapped element in a variable, you gain slightly in efficiency.

---

In rare cases, `this` might already be a jQuery wrapper. The case that comes up often for me is when writing jQuery plugins. In that case you can do things like `this.attr("id")` directly, without wrapping it up first, because it's already wrapped. In the usual cases (event handlers, `$.each`, etc.) the wrapper is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, great answer. And that last part helps explain something I read somewhere but could find it again.  I saw `this.attr("id")` used, but it didn't work for me.  I think that is what confused me the most.

Answer (score 8):

'this' is a Javascript object keyword for referring to the current object, '$(this)' is the jQuery wrapper function that turns the current object into a jQuery object, and when you see '$this' it usually refers to a variable that the developer created to refer to the $(this) object, it's useful during a $.each loop. For example:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // refers to the $('a') object
    $('div').each(function(){
      $(this).hide(); // $(this) refers to each 'div' in the loop, not the $('a')
      $this.css({ color: 'blue' }); // turns the link element text blue
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you expound your answer to show when and why the plain `this` could come into play

Comment: The only reason to use the plain 'this' in this situation is if you need to access a method or variable on the raw DOM Node such as here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_node.asp
For example you would not be able to use a jQuery method on the plain 'this' such as: this.hide();

Comment: Oh...I see. So would it be safe to say that whatever 'operation' you perform on `this` would have the possibility of being non cross-browser compliant? Whereas wrapping it in `$()` and using a jQuery method would be lots safer? It might be good to update your answer to reflect these implications of `this` since the OP wanted to know about that

Comment: No performing an operation on `this` won't make it less compliant. Wrapping it in `$()` just gives you the functionality that jQuery brings to the table and they have been very careful about making their methods very cross-browser compatible. So using `$(this)` in actuality is less cross-browser compliant than `this` only if the jQuery team missed something. `$(this)` has the same methods as `this` plus all methods of the jQuery object. The OP was confused about the `$this` variable he saw used in other developers code but that variable is just a cached version of `$(this)` usually.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is a native Javascript object that refers to the current object. In jQuery functions defined with `jQuery.fn.`, `this` is a jQuery object by itself. `$(this)` is jQuery's way of turning a Javascript `this` into a jQuery object. And `$this` is just a variable name. If you haven't defined it, it would be `undefined`.

Here's a good explanation of jQuery's usage of `this`:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this

Comment: `this` is not just used in event handlers, it is a reference to the current object. Here's a further explanation: http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling `$(this)` multiple times, it's more efficient to store it as a variable, usually called `$this` so that people know what it is.