# 'this' object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, this

Can someone let me know what is the difference between `this` and `jQuery(this)`? I found that my code works if I use '`this`' and if I use `jQuery(this)` it does not work. Does `jQuery(this`) not query for the current object and return it?

I want to know the index of the image being clicked ( I now we have the index() method, but still want it through the below logic)
Here is the full code:(edited as per request)

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
jQuery("#div1").append("<img src='slider.jpg'>");
}
imgArr=jQuery("#div1>img");
jQuery("#div1>img").click(display);
function display()
{
  for(i=0;i<imgArr.length;i++)
  {
     if(this==imgArr[i])
     {
      alert(i);
     }
  }
}
```

Here if I replace `this` with `jQuery(this)` it does not work.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719635/jquery-this-versus-this-and-maybe-even-this

Comment: it depends on the context it's in; could you show us more of the code? i.e. the function this is part of?

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what 'this' is... JavaScript scoping is hard enough without seeing it out of context!  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose "this" is a reference to a DOM element in your first example?

jQuery(this) is actually a jQuery wrapper around one or more DOM elements. So when you compare to a DOM element, it will never be equal.

If you want the DOM element from a jQuery wrapper, use the indexer to get the first element:

```
jQuery(this)[0] === this
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Now I understand it better.